# MySQL: Get rows from another table as columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

Users:

```
id  name
1   bob
2   joe
3   paul
```

Possessions:

```
id  user_id type        name
1   1       car         honda
2   1       computer    mac
3   2       car         toyota
4   2       computer    pc
5   2       phone       htc
6   3       car         toyota
7   3       computer    pc
8   3       phone       samsung
```

I would like to create a query such that I get this as output:

```
user_id name    car     computer    phone
1       bob     honda   mac 
2       joe     toyota  pc          htc
3       paul    toyota  pc          samsung
```

Can I do this without using subqueries? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: please post us the create of the tables and the insert of data. then i will write you a query

Comment: Are the columns fixed (column count and names that is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of types is fixed, you could use a query like this:

```
select
  p.user_id,
  u.name,
  max(case when p.type='car' then p.name end) as car,
  max(case when p.type='computer' then p.name end) as computer,
  max(case when p.type='phone' then p.name end) as phone
from
  possesions p inner join users u
  on p.user_id=u.id
group by
  p.user_id,
  u.name
```

explanation: `case when` will return `p.name` when the condition is true, and null otherwise. Here we are grouping by user_id and name, and `max()` will return the maximum non-null value per each group.

Comment: Great, thank you. I was doing this exact same thing except I wasn't wrapping the max function around the case statements. Would you mind explaining what that is doing?

Comment: I don't think this would work if a person had more than one car, computer, etc.

Comment: @mseifert you're right, I assume that every type can be specified only once per user. If this is not the case, instead of max () we could use group_concat () for example...